# Recorrido Anchura (ABB arbol binario de busqueda)

Tags: java, árboles-binarios

**El problema es que al imprimir solo me salen los datos de la izquierda no todos en fila de cada nivel. Es decir si pongo la secuencia 15, 9, ,20, 6.
No me imprime el 20 del nivel 1. Y si en la funcion de anchura pongo primero el if de la derecha me pasa lo contrario solo me imprime los valores de la derecha no lo de la izquierda ni los del medio
clase nodo del arbol:**

```
public class Nodo {

    public Nodo izquierda;
    public Nodo derecha;
    public int edad;
    
    public Nodo()
    {
        izquierda = derecha = null;
    }
}
```

**Clase arbol binario contiene la funcion de recorrido por anchura**

```
public void recorrerNiveles(Nodo actual)
{
    int nivel = 0;
    Nodo aux;
    Cola cola = new Cola();
    
    System.out.print("\nEl recorrido en anchura es: \n");
    
    if(actual != null)
    {
        cola.insertarEnCola(actual);
        while(!(cola.colaVacia()))
        {
            aux = cola.inicio.dato;
            
            cola.eliminarInicio();
            
            System.out.println(aux.edad + " Nivel " + nivel);
          
            if(aux.izquierda != null)
            {
                cola.insertarEnCola(aux.izquierda);
            }
            
             if(aux.derecha != null)
            {
                cola.insertarEnCola(aux.derecha);
            }
            
            nivel++;
        }
        
    }
    cola.recorrer(cola.inicio);
    System.out.println();
}
```

**En la cola tengo una funcio de cola vacia si o no funcion de insertar nodo o eliminarlo de la cola asi como la funcion recorrer cola**

```
public class Cola {

    int tamaño;
  public  NodoCola inicio;
  public  NodoCola salida;
    
    public Cola()
    {
        tamaño = 0;
        inicio = null;
        salida = null;
    }
    
    
    
    public boolean colaVacia()
    {
        if(inicio == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    public void insertarEnCola(Nodo actual)
    {
        if(colaVacia() == true)
        {
            inicio = new NodoCola(actual);
            salida = new NodoCola(actual);
        }
        else{
           NodoCola aux = salida;
            salida = new NodoCola(actual);
            aux.siguiente = new NodoCola(actual);
        }
        tamaño++;
    }
    
    public void recorrer(NodoCola actual)
    {
        if(actual != null)
        {
            System.out.print("\n" + actual.dato.edad + " <-- ");
            recorrer(actual.siguiente);
        }
    }
    
    public void eliminarInicio()
    {
        if(inicio != null)
        {
            inicio = inicio.siguiente;
        }
        tamaño--;
    }
```

**Clase NodoCola esta clase seran los nodos del arbol pero insertando los en la cola, por eso hay conversion de tipos de datos**

```
public class NodoCola {

   public Nodo dato;
   public NodoCola siguiente;
    
    //Construtor  Crea un nodo del tipo Object
    public NodoCola(Nodo actual)
    {
        dato = actual;
        siguiente = null; //siguiente con valor nulo
    }



   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas para quien este igual que yo lo resolvi de la siguiente manera.

```
public void recorrerAnchura(String vec[], int i)
{
    imprimirPorNivel(raiz, 0, vec);
    for(i = 0; i < vec.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(vec[i] + " En nivel: " + i);
    }
}


public void imprimirPorNivel(Nodo actual, int i, String []vec)
{
    if(actual != null)
    {
        String dato = actual.edad + " , " + ((vec[i] != null) ? vec[i] : "");
        vec[i] = dato;
         imprimirPorNivel(actual.derecha, i + 1, vec);
        imprimirPorNivel(actual.izquierda, i + 1, vec);
    }
}
```